# Is perPixelTargetFind valid with objects created with freeDrawingBrush?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Does `perPixelTargetFind` work with objects created by `freeDrawingBrush`? Same for specifying `cornerColor`, etc. I am able to select the free-drawn objects but only by the bounding box and the controls are the default.

*(It's been a while since I worked with `Fabric.js` so sorry if this is a too-basic question. Also, while I am here: are there any more "user friendly" forms of the Fabric.js documentation than the `JSDocs` which exist at http://fabricjs.com? Those docs are fine but it is difficult to get an overview of properties except by scrolling through entire pages)*

---

I create my `PencilBrush` like this:

```
 this.object = new fabric.PencilBrush(this.canvas, {
  width: this.strokeWidth,
  color: this.stroke,
  perPixelTargetFind: true,
  cornerColor: "#ff0000",
  borderColor: "#00ff00",
  hasBorders: true,
  hasControls: true
});
this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush = this.object
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the docs for [canvas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#perPixelTargetFind) I discovered that I can set `perPixelTargetFind` for the canvas itself rather than for the individual shape instances as I had been doing, so now paths created with the `freeDrawingBrush` brush are selectable by their painted areas only rather than by their bounding boxes

```
   this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl, {
      perPixelTargetFind :true
    });
```